# check current date is falling in restricted date, time and day JAVA

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I am designing for banking application, where user is not allowed to login in particular time.

For example restricted time would be :-

```
Date : 2022-01-28 to 2022-05-28
Time : 1:00 AM to 4:00 AM
Day  : Mon, Tue, Fri
```

Restricted duration would be configured in database and I need to do restriction check in Service/DAO layer using Java Code.

I found multiple answers for checking date and time but not for Day.

Can anyone provide consolidated answer for comparing all Date,Time and Day.
Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  Use the [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"};
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2022,1,25);
for (String d : days) {
    System.out.println(DayOfWeek.valueOf(d.toUpperCase())
          .equals(today.getDayOfWeek()));
}
```

prints

```
false
true
false
```

You could also do something like.

```
String allowed = "MON TUE FRI";
boolean result = allowed.contains(today.getDayOfWeek().name()
           .substring(0,3));
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You said:

> I found multiple answers for checking date and time but not for Day.

```
// Is today Monday? 
LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )
```

## Time zone

You omitted a crucial element: time zone. I will ignore that if you are certain your software applies only locally to a single time zone. I do not recommend ignoring time zone, but I'll follow your lead on this one.

## Record

Define a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to represent your restricted rules set.

```
record LoginForbidden ( 
    LocalDate startDate , LocalDate endDate , 
    LocalTime startTime , LocalTime endTime , 
    Set< DayOfWeek > dows 
) {}
```

## Database

Retrieve the date and time objects using JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
LocalDate startDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
…
LocalTime startTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
…
```

For day-of-week, there is no SQL standard data type. So I suggest you store either 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or the all uppercase string name of each [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object (`MONDAY`, `TUESDAY`, etc.). Retrieve as an `int` or `String`, respectively. Obtain a `DayOfWeek` object by calling `DayOfWeek.values()[myOrdinalDowNumber-1]` or [`DayOfWeek.valueOf( String )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), respectively.

## Current moment

Capture the current moment. Doing so requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date and time-of-day both vary around the globe by zone. If you omit the time zone, *java.time* uses the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;
```

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate today = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Search your collection of `LoginForbidden` objects (`loginForbiddens`) for the current date.

```
List< LoginForbidden > loginForbiddensForToday = 
        loginForbiddens
        .stream()
        .filter(
            loginForbidden -> ( ! today.isBefore( startDate ) ) && today.isBefore( loginForbidden.endDate ) 
        )
        .toList()
;
```

We should find exactly one object, I presume. So verify.

```
if( loginForbiddensForToday.size() != 1 ) { throw new IllegalStateException( "Other than one LoginForbidden found for date: " + today.toString()   ) ; }
```

If valid, extract the one and only object.

```
LoginForbidden loginForbiddenForToday = loginForbiddens.get( 0 ) ;
```

## Day of week

Proceed, comparing the day of week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
boolean dayForbidden = loginForbiddenForToday.dows().contains( dow ) ;
```

## Time of day

If the day is forbidden, then move on to compare current time-of-day against the start and stop times.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
boolean denyLogin = ( ! lt.isBefore( loginForbiddenForToday.startTime() ) ) && lt.isBefore( loginForbiddenForToday.endTime() ) ;
```

This is all rough-draft, **untested code**. But it should get you pointed in the right direction.